# Can I get an RSS of the top Digg Technology items only?

Tags: digg, rss

I currently subscribe to Digg technology feed in my Google Reader. But I can't possibly keep up with the 900 posts a day that it gets (almost as much as TechCrunch).

Is there a way to get only the "Top Items" in a feed? (See Image)

Alternatively just getting items with a certain number of Diggs (say 200) so I only get the really good stuff?

Is there another filter option that I can use that I'm not thinking of for viewing just the most popular items?

[alt text http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/7291/diggy.png](http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/7291/diggy.png)

Comment: Same as other comment Feed it through a Yahoo Pipe. someone will take the *hint*

Comment: The image is no longer available.

Answer (score 4):

Is http://feeds.digg.com/digg/container/technology/popular.rss what you want?